# Service worker not returning custom offline page it is instead returning the default "offline" page

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I have a service worker that I want to return an offline page if you're offline. I realized you have to cache the offline page first, so I did that. When I had it cached, and I used chrome dev tools to throttle the network to offline, it showed the default offline page! I don't know how to bring up the page when it is offline. I'm on a chromebook if that would change anything. Here's my code (by the way I am completely new to service workers):

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
 event.waitUntil(
 caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
   return cache.addAll(['../offline.html','../images/ico/ico.jpg']); 
 })
 );
});
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
       caches.match(event.request)
           .then(function(response) {
               // If fetch fails, we return offline.html from cache.
               return fetch(event.request)
                   .catch(err => {
                       return caches.match('../offline.html');
                   });
           }
       )
   );
});
```

Comment: It looks like the tutorial I was reading (https://dev.to/saurabhdaware/make-websites-work-offline-part-1-what-are-service-workers-and-how-to-get-a-custom-app-install-button-on-the-website-4a8) doesn't tell me that the service worker has to be in the root domain that I will be handling requests for. Google dev explains this better (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your fetch event code with this one. For every request your fetch event will be invoked and it will check if your request is found in the cache file list then it will serve the file from there otherwise it will make the fetch call to get the file from server.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      try {
        // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported.
        const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
        if (preloadResponse) {
          return preloadResponse;
        }

        const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResponse;
      } catch (error) {
        // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
        // due to a network error.
        // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
        // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
        console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);

        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
        return cachedResponse;
      }
    })());
  }

  // If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't intercept the
  // request. If there are any other fetch handlers registered, they will get a
  // chance to call event.respondWith(). If no fetch handlers call
  // event.respondWith(), the request will be handled by the browser as if there
  // were no service worker involvement.
});
```

Comment: I want to fetch an offline page however, that will show that the user is offline instead of adding the cached version. Is that possible? Couldn't I just change the bottom `return fetch(event.request);` with `return fetch('page-to-offline-html-page.html');`?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Add your offline.html page into your cached list.

Comment: (sorry it took so long to respond, was busy with something else) still doesn't work. Still gives default offline page (chrome offline page). Also, await doesn't work with service workers I guess.

Comment: try this.https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/#:~:text=The%20service%20worker%20handles%20all,and%20then%20reload%20this%20page.

Comment: I have updated the code, give this a try. This should definitely work.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I think I know why. The fetch function does not work.

Comment: if your service worker is registered successfully then your fetch function will definitely work.

Comment: It works now (I just didn't have it in the root directory). Thanks, I'll mark your question as the answer.