# Service worker not displaying fallback page

Tags: javascript, promise, service-worker

This fetch event handler of a service worker fails to display the fallback page.

The sw is supposed to check the request if it exist in the cache and if not, fetch it from the network. Then a conditional to make sure I get valid response or else display a fallback error page as last resort. So the issue here is even when all the logic is met, the fallback page fails to display. It is definitely preached as static asset and is in the root directory as the sw.

This is what the file structure looks like: Public/(index.html, fallback.html, sw.js)

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  if (e.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && e.request.mode !== 
      'same-origin') {
      return;
     }
  caches.match(e.request).then(res => {
      return res || fetch(e.request).then(res => {
          if(res.ok && res.url){
              return res
          } else {
             return caches.match('/fallback.html')
          }
        })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you are not returning anything if `res.ok && res.url` is false. And you don't `catch` anything if one of the promises rejects.

Comment: Check this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64504700/1289713)

Comment: @VimalPatel I had tried that solution before but did not solve the problem

Comment: What is the issue you are facing

Comment: @derpirscher that's my bad. In the actual code I did `return caches.match('/fallback.html')` if the condition was false. Sadly, issue remains. This is probably the 6th snippet I tried to implement yet nothing. Interestingly just above `return caches.match('/fallback.html')`, I had `console.log('displaying fallback')` which ran every time but the fallback page never got displayed. I guess if the string get logged every time this means the promise will always resolve thus no error to catch.

Comment: @VimalPatel fallback still didn't display. I even added extra console.log on each block but nothing.

Comment: Please update the code which you have tried .Also mentioned the step you are taking to view the fallback page

Comment: Again: You are working with promises here, but I don't see any `.catch()` to deal with  a situation where one of them rejects ... try adding some errorhandling. maybe `caches.match('/fallback.html')` rejects and therefore the page is not displayed.

Comment: @derpirscher it logged this error on first load: TypeError: ```Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode``` That was the only time.