# Service Worker (sw.js) should always return offline.html document if there is no network connection

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

I'm having an issue with a service worker that's working partially. The manifest defines the `start_url` correctly (https://example.com/start.html) for users that add the website to the Homescreen, and both the start.html and offline.html are cached correctly as well, and both are available while the browser has no internet connection.

If the user gets offline (no network connection), the service worker successfully serves both *https://example.com/start.html* and *https://example.com/offline.html* -- but if the user tries opening anything else (e.g. https://example.com/something.html) the browser throws a "site can't be reached" error message.

What I actually need, is that, if there is no network connection, the service worker *always* returns the offline.html cached document, no matter which url the user is trying to reach.

In other words, the problem is that the Service Worker is not properly serving offline.html for the user's requests when there's no network connection (whatever solution is found, it also needs to cache the start.html for the manifest's start_url).

This is my current code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "My Basic Example",
    "short_name": "Example",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "https://example.com/static/ico/manifest-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://example.com/static/ico/manifest-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any maskable"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "https://example.com/start.html",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "background_color": "#2196f3",
    "theme_color": "#2196f3"
}
```

**core.js**

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {
        scope: '/'
    }).then(function(registration) {
    }).catch(function(err) {
    });
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
    });
}
```

**sw.js**

```
const PRECACHE = 'cache-v1';
const RUNTIME = 'runtime';
const PRECACHE_URLS = [
    '/offline.html',
    '/start.html'
];
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(PRECACHE)
        .then(cache => cache.addAll(PRECACHE_URLS))
        .then(self.skipWaiting())
    );
});
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    const currentCaches = [PRECACHE, RUNTIME];
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return cacheNames.filter(cacheName => !currentCaches.includes(cacheName));
        })
        .then(cachesToDelete => {
            return Promise.all(cachesToDelete.map(cacheToDelete => {
                return caches.delete(cacheToDelete);
            }));
        })
        .then(() => self.clients.claim())
    );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if(event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
                if(cachedResponse) {
                    return cachedResponse;
                }
                return caches.open(RUNTIME).then(cache => {
                    return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
                        return cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).then(() => {
                            return response;
                        });
                    });
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code for showing offline page in case of no connection? Yet you said offline page is showing. Are you manually navigating to that page?

Comment: @VimalPatel i meant that if you go to offline.html while offline, it will be cached, but there is no code for showing the offline.html when trying to access any other resource. That's what i need help with :)

Comment: Check out this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64504700/1289713 Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: @VimalPatel partially. It solves the offline issue for any resources while there is no network connection, but now there's no access (via fetch) to the start.html if the user accesses via Homescreen while being offline.

Comment: Did you add the "start.html" in your cache list? if there is default page configure then try adding "/" in your cache list and it will work.

Comment: @VimalPatel yes, i added start.html to the cache list as well. The only issue remaining with that solution, is that if the user is offline, and tries to access start.html, offline.html will be displayed. But in *that* specific case, since start.html is cached, that same file should be displayed instead.

Comment: As I said you might try to add '/' in cache list if default document is set in webserver. Can you share your application url?

Comment: @VimalPatel the app is still in a development environment, so I can't share a url yet :( -- i also added '/' to the cache list but the issue still persists. While being offline if I try opening the root '/' or '/start.html', the cached resource won't be displayed, and offline.html cached content will be displayed instead.

Comment: It should work, without debugging difficult to say the root cause. Can you verify when you are online , start,html page is served from service worker cached instead of server?

Comment: @VimalPatel thanks for your help, a solution with code that fixes the issue was posted a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code worked as expected, but you needed a check to see if the user was requesting `start.html`. I took the code from [Create an offline fallback page](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/) and modified it to suit your request.

```js
// Incrementing OFFLINE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force
// previously cached resources to be updated from the network.
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";
// Customize this with a different URL if needed.
const START_URL = "start.html";
const OFFLINE_URL = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the
      // response isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from
      // the network.
      await Promise.all([
        cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: "reload" })),
        cache.add(new Request(START_URL, { cache: "reload" })),
      ]);
    })()
  );
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
      // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
      if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
        await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
      }
    })()
  );

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
  if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
                  
          // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported.
          const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
          if (preloadResponse) {
            return preloadResponse;
          }

          // Always try the network first.
          const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
          return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
          // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
          // due to a network error.
          // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
          // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
          console.log("Fetch failed; returning cached page instead.", error);

          const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
          if (event.request.url.includes(START_URL)) {
            return await cache.match(START_URL);
          }
          return await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
        }
      })()
    );
  }

  // If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't intercept the
  // request. If there are any other fetch handlers registered, they will get a
  // chance to call event.respondWith(). If no fetch handlers call
  // event.respondWith(), the request will be handled by the browser as if there
  // were no service worker involvement.
});
```

One thing to note with this, once `start.html` has been cached when the service worker is first installed, it will **not** be updated again until the service worker is updated. That means your users may see an old/outdated `start.html` any time they're offline and load your app. You probably want to use a [network first strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache) for `start.html`.

You can try the [working demo](https://basic-pwa-so-1.glitch.me/) and [source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/basic-pwa-so-1?path=sw.js)

Comment: Hi @PeteLe thanks for the reply, it seems to solve the issue but I have a question before accepting the answer: If the browser is set to offline, i'm getting this error (through sw.js): `The service worker navigation preload request failed with network error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.` [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/BpDpbLr) --- in that specific example, i reloaded the site 20 times. As I understand it, the service worker is trying to update the cached resources on each load. Shouldn't that happen only once, and then again only if `OFFLINE_VERSION` is incremented?

Comment: The only time the service worker will update the cached resource (in this implementation) is during the `install` event. The error you're seeing happens each time the page loads. The service worker intercepts the HTTP requests, tries to hit the network for the file, but it fails because it's offline, so it throws that error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The bounty has been awarded to your account :) -- btw, do you have any idea what could be causing this related issue in Google's Lighthouse PWA checklist? Basically it returns a "start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline" error [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/gljFxF3). If `start.html` is already cached, why is the Lighthouse not recognizing the resource as available while offline? I posted this question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268076/lighthouse-pwa-audit-returns-a-start-url-does-not-respond-with-a-200-when-offli).