# Lighthouse PWA audit returns a "start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline" error

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

I'm having an issue with Lighthouse's PWA audit. I'm using a Service Worker `sw.js` that successfully caches both the `offline.html` fallback (for when the user has no network connection), and the `start.html` (which is defined as `start_url` in the `manifest.json` and is displayed if the user opens the website from the Homescreen icon).

The issue happens when I use Lighthouse to validate the PWA checklist, which throws this (only) error:

> start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
> The start_url did respond, but not via a service worker.

[image: Lighthouse result]

I find this odd, because `start.html` is properly cached upon the service worker install process. My only guess is that the validator is trying to access `start.html` in offline mode before the service worker can actually cache it to the browser storage.

So, how can I validate that particular issue in Lighthouse's PWA checklist?

Here's my current code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "My Basic Example",
    "short_name": "Example",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "https://example.com/static/ico/manifest-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any maskable"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "https://example.com/start.html",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "background_color": "#2196f3",
    "theme_color": "#2196f3"
}
```

**core.js**

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {
        scope: '/'
    }).then(function(registration) {
    }).catch(function(err) {
    });
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
    });
}
```

**sw.js**

```
//cache container
const CACHE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = 'cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION;

//resources
const URL_OFFLINE = 'offline.html';
const URL_START = 'start.html';

//install
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
            await Promise.all([
                cache.add(new Request(URL_OFFLINE, { cache: 'reload' })),
                cache.add(new Request(URL_START, { cache: 'reload' }))
            ]);
        })()
    );

    //force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker
    self.skipWaiting();
});

//activate
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            //enable navigation preload if it is supported.
            //https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
            if('navigationPreload' in self.registration) {
                await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
            }
        })()
    );

    //tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately
    self.clients.claim();
});

//fetch
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    //we only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request for an HTML page
    if(event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
        event.respondWith((async () => {
            try {
                //first, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported
                const preload_response = await event.preload_response;
                if(preload_response) {
                    return preload_response;
                }

                //always try the network first
                const network_response = await fetch(event.request);
                return network_response;
            } catch (error) {
                //catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely due to a network error
                const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
                if(event.request.url.includes(URL_START)) {
                    return await cache.match(URL_START);
                }
                return await cache.match(URL_OFFLINE);
            }
        })());
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your service worker is being served from the root, right now it's being served from a relative directory, and that could be affecting things. Otherwise compare what you have to the sample I linked to in your other question - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/basic-pwa-so-1 - to see what's different.

Comment: Also, if you have a query string or anything else on your `start_url` that will affect the way the service worker responds.

Comment: @PeteLe Thanks, i'll have to test the site running it from the root.

Answer (score 0):

@PeteLe, I tried your sample and got following failure:

Navigated to https://basic-pwa-so-1.glitch.me/

The service worker navigation preload request failed with network error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.

Looks like something was updated in Lighthouse generating the error message